# PHP MySQL in 1 class & 1 file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a many-in-one PHP MySQL 1 class/file with the features:

1. Connect to DB server
2. Select database
3. CRUD
4. Prepare & binding

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little something I wrote a while back:

> [MySQL Class](http://pastebin.com/f519de798)

Then you can just query as such:

```
$mysql = new MySQL('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'somedb');
$mysql->open();
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT field FROM table WHERE field = '%s';", 'Some Value');

while($row = $mysql->fetch($result)) { echo $row['field']; }
```

It will automatically escape your values, provided you use `sprintf()` type syntax. Not exactly what you asked but close.

For a more complete package, you might want to look at [PEAR::MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2).

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Good job on that! I just need a simple one and your is quite complete for my needs!

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search I [found this](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4222.html).

You could modify / extend it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you Christian! This class is simple enough.